# RPI destroys usb storage

Tags: usb, pi-3b+

I use my RaspberryPI 3B+ with the system installed on USB storage sticks (no SD card at all). Raspbian is installed in server mode, with Apache, MySQL, FTP, ... I use it mainly as web server with an RSS feed reader (similar to Tiny Tiny RSS) and as webcast player.

One month ago, the USB stick I was using from about one year suddenly stopped working. Apache was still running but replied with errors, and the HDMI output showed nothing (no prompt).

I tested the USB stick in a computer, and the device appeared as an empty storage container (no usable space, Windows sees it as "Removable" with "No media"). I concluded the USB stick was dead, at started a fresh install on another USB key ([Intenso USB2 8GB](https://www.reichelt.com/de/fr/cl-usb-2-0-8-go-intenso-rainbow-line-intenso-rbl-8gb-p78758.html)).

But now, one month later, the new stik is also dead, with the same symptoms.

`fdisk -l` does not show the disk. Same for `df`.
`lsusb` sees it though.

How can I try and find out more about the cause?

---

Addition of Goldilocks' suggested commands' results:

```
gwen@gwen-VirtualBox:~/Bureau$ sudo dd if=~/MBR.img of=/dev/sdb
dd: impossible d'ouvrir '/dev/sdb': Aucun support trouvé

gwen@gwen-VirtualBox:~/Bureau$ tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog
...
May 15 18:49:07 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63155.293199] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ohci-pci
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.436565] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.436568] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x2 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.454264] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3000, bcdDevice= 1.00
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.454267] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.454268] usb 1-2: Product: SM3255AA MEMORY BAR 
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.454269] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.459052] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 15 18:49:08 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63156.459554] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 20: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2"
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 20 was not an MTP device
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox upowerd[1133]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox upowerd[1133]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-2
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63157.496855] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63157.500254] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
May 15 18:49:09 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63157.550989] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
May 15 18:51:10 gwen-VirtualBox kernel: [63277.664604] usb 1-2: reset full-speed USB device number 20 using ohci-pci

gwen@gwen-VirtualBox:~/Bureau$ dmesg | tail -n 50
...
[63155.293199] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ohci-pci
[63156.436565] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[63156.436568] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x2 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[63156.454264] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3000, bcdDevice= 1.00
[63156.454267] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[63156.454268] usb 1-2: Product: SM3255AA MEMORY BAR 
[63156.454269] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[63156.459052] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[63156.459554] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[63157.496855] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[63157.500254] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[63157.550989] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[63277.664604] usb 1-2: reset full-speed USB device number 20 using ohci-pci
```

Comment: Windows is probably not the best thing to examine devices containing filesystems it cannot read, because (as far as I'm aware) the normal tools do not say something sensible (such as "ext4 partition", even if it can't be read beyond that, it can certainly be identified), they instead ignore it or present some not-really-correct scenario.  In any case, there's not much anyone can say here based on the information available.

Comment: @goldilocks I also tried in a Linux VM, but i'm not an expert... I have a /dev/sdb but no sdb1. In any case, I don't get why the partitions are wiped out. I was more looking on advice on an hardware cause than on  a logical reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fdisk -l` does not show the disk. Same for `df`. `lsusb` sees it though.
>
> How can I try and find out more about the cause?

This implies the immediate cause was corruption which affected the partition table; that "Apache was still running but replied with errors" fits with this, since the information in the partition table is only needed when mounting a partition.  You can delete the entire table and the system should be mostly fine until a reboot.

As to what would have caused the corruption, power could be an issue.  If you recover the filesystems, try `sudo grep "Under-voltage" /var/log/syslog` and see if that clue is there.

Of course if the partition table was corrupted, likely other data was as well.  I've never run a Pi directly from a USB device,<sup>1</sup> but I assume it is [DOS MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) formatted like the primary SD card would be, and not GPT (which there is not much purpose to that in this context).  The MBR, which contains the partition table, is only a 512 byte block.

The thing to do in that case is to recreate the partition table with `fdisk`.  This is one of two fundamental steps in formatting a block storage device, the other being creating the filesystems.  The latter is what effectively "wipes" the storage, because it replaces the information needed to find specific pieces of data -- although the data will still be there, sorting it out may be difficult or impossible and is not a worthwhile pursuit in this context.

That means if you rewrite the partition table exactly as it was before, you will be able to access whatever is left of the filesystems. Which could be quite a bit, since the only thing you know for sure is damaged (this all assumes the problem is not a physical defect or damage to the stick) is the 512 byte partition table.

The easiest way to do this is to simple keep a copy of the MBR.  From a running Pi, and referring to the SD card:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=mbr.copy bs=512 count=1
```

You would use `/dev/sda` or whatever it is (note, *not* `sda[N]`, where `N` is a number; that refers to partitions and not the block device itself.  This leaves you with a 512 byte file you can stash somewhere(s) easily.

To replace it:

```
dd if=mbr.copy of=/dev/sda
```

Here I'm using `sda` to make it clear this probably isn't in a running system since at that point the storage has been borked.  It is possible though, eg., if you had been able to log in in the "apache was still running scenario".

You probably won't be allowed to do that if a partition on the device is currently mounted (it which case you should umount said parition(s)).

You could also do this from saved `fdisk -l` output but that is a bit tedious.  Since you don't have either here, you could consult the original image used to create the card (you can run `fdisk -l` on a pi image file).  Most likely, that's never been changed *except* to expand the root fs.  If what you did was just fill the device, this is pretty simple.  If you arbitrary divided into multiple partition, though, this may be tricky or impossible.

---

1. You might want to reconsider that strategy unless you have a good reason for doing so (an by that I do not mean, "it's got a faster read/write time", but that you actually need such in order to accomplish some goal).  Obviously enough, it is not a safeguard against block storage corruption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Copying the MBR with `dd` fails with `dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found`. I added the dmesg log in the question, if it can help.
About the power outage part, I recently switched from a smartphone charger to an official raspberry power unit... Thus I didn't want to consider the power problem option, but this problem has arrived at the same time as the new power adapter. I'll switch back to the old adapter to see if my thirdusb stick will survive longer.

Comment: If `dd` doesn't work and the device is otherwise usuable, you've done something wrong or there is something mysteriously wrong with the hardware (`tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` are good things to check immediately after the call and should show something if it is hardware failure).

Comment: Thanks again, i added the results of dmesg and syslog after the dd command.

Comment: It may be because of virtualbox -- in which case the french "no support found" is more revealing than "no medium" -- **OR**, more likely, it's because you are trying to write to a device that is currently mounted.  I haven't ran into that enough to recognize it (maybe because I don't use automounting), but a quick search online of `dd "no medium"` turns up a lot of "all I had to do was unmount it".

Comment: Well, I can't see anything mounted. There is /dev/sdb that appears when the usb is attached to the virtual box, but no sdb1... Can sdb be mounted at all ?

Comment: Should have been more explicit and said, "currently *has a partition* mounted".  That would probably include by the host, but I guess it is unlikely if the partition table is wrecked and there are no partitions apparent to mount.  Or perhaps it is virtualbox. You should be able to apply `dd` regardless of what formatting has or hasn't been done to the device.   It would require `sudo` but you get "permission denied" for that.

Comment: I tried directly on the Raspberry Pi, the result is the same... I think the USB devices are definitly fried, because even a low level formating with the tools from the vendor of the controller chip fails.
Results of the tests on the Raspberry in the next comment.

Comment: __pi@rpi:~ $ ls /dev/sd*__

/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb


__pi@rpi:~ $ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.copy bs=512 count=1__

1+0 records in

1+0 records out

512 bytes copied, 0.472608 s, 1.1 kB/s


__pi@rpi:~ $ sudo dd if=mbr.copy of=/dev/sdb__

dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found        

__pi@rpi:~ $ cat /proc/mounts__

/dev/root / ext4 rw,noatime 0 0

...

/dev/sda1 /boot vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0

...